# Sort emacs dired buffer according to custom comparator

Tags: sorting, emacs, elisp, dired

It does not seem that dired provides an interface to sort the files/folders according to an arbitrary comparator function. (By default it only allows sorting by name and by date).

I have been digging into the source code in order to determine the mechanism for this sorting, and I see that it is the call to `(revert-buffer)` in `dired-sort-toggle` (in `dired.el`) which does the redisplaying. This leads me to realize that dired simply runs an ls command with certain switches, and then reads the output into the buffer.

Is there a better way to achieve this custom sorting than to point dired's ls function to a custom one? I feel that there could be a variable which holds the ordered list of files/directories in the dired buffer, which I could potentially re-arrange.

I have found the variable `dired-subdir-alist`, but this only seems to contain the top directory (even though according to the documentation, this seems like exactly the list I want)

> dired-subdir-alist is a variable defined in `dired.el'.
>   Documentation: Association list of subdirectories and their buffer
>   positions. Each subdirectory has an element: (DIRNAME . STARTMARKER).
>   The order of elements is the reverse of the order in the buffer. In
>   simple cases, this list contains one element.

How could I find such a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct.  And, as @Stefan notes, `ls-lisp.el` provides some flexibility.

See also library [Dired Sort Menu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu), which at least provides more `ls` possibilities and lets you combine sort orders.  (It does not let you provide an arbitrary sort order, however -- for that, see `ls-lisp.el`.)

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use ls-lisp, which is an Elisp implementation of `insert-directory`, which is the function used by Dired to (normally) run ls.  This is used typically under Windows where `ls` is often absent:

```
(require 'ls-lisp)
```

It should be easy to tweak the code to be able to use your own sorting function.

Comment: I will look into this. I did eventually track down that it was this `insert-directory` the function that was really responsible for the order of the files and directories.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but this is the top hit when searching on this issue.

Instead of mucking around in ls-lisp internals, it was easier to implement a sorting function (e.g., with `sort-regexp-fields`) and bind it to `dired-mode-map`.  You have to temporarily inhibit read-only mode to do this.  E.g., I have a directory with files in format "FIELD1==FIELD2--FIELD3" and I want to sort by FIELD2:

```
(defun my-sort-field2 ()
  (interactive)
  (setq inhibit-read-only t)
  (sort-regexp-fields nil "^.*$" "==.*--" (point-min) (point-max))
  (setq inhibit-read-only nil))
```

This will let you do all kinds of arbitrary sorting and manipulation of `insert-directory` results.  For example, you can restrict the sorting above to specific a specific directory by wrapping it in a conditional.